# Redirection using PHP footer in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, placeholder

I have a question about timed redirects in PHP - specifically in wordpress.

We have setup a site using a free Woothemes placeholder theme, it is very limited.  But that is OK - the site is simple.

After 20 seconds I would like the page to redirect to another URL - would it be possible to insert some code into footer.php to do this? I have found what looks like the right code:

// Redirect with a delay:
`header('Refresh: 20; url=http://www.example.org/');`

Can this be inserted antwhere in footer.php?

Any input is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried it? No reason why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can write simply in header.php

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="20;URL=http://www.google.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be used in the footer. But make sure you have set `ob_start()` in the header. Otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be inserted, but in case some HTML is already by the server you will receive an warning such as `header already sent by .....` and the redirection will not function as it should.

Instead you can perform such by clearing everything in the output buffer using [ob_clear()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) that is to be printed and then send the redirection header.

Example:

```
if($casespecial==true) {
    ob_clean(); //make sure nothing is outputed to the browser
    header('Refresh: 20; url=http://www.example.org/'); //now send the header param

    //After wards, you can resume your normal code and output the template as you require
    .
    .
    .
}
```